# PCI/internal sound card not detected on Dell E7470

Tags: drivers, sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.5, I am using a [Dell Latitude E7470 with a Realtek 3235 chipset](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/latitude-e7470-ultrabook/Late_E7470_OM/Audio-specifications?guid=GUID-EE1BF4E5-7FF1-4415-A32D-B8FE54B2D639&lang=en-us). This morning I upgraded to Kernel 4.4 and the sound stopped working. Currently no sound devices are detected, I went trough the [sound troubleshooting document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) to no avail.

No soundcards appear to be detected:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---

$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

$ dmesg | grep -i hda
<no output>
```

It looks I am in the situation described [by this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1577654) and I do not know exactly what to do to get out of it. I googled for at least three hours, trying a lot of possible solution without no success. The sound was working this morning, so unless some hardware accident happened in the meantime I have no explanation for this disappearance.

Can anybody give me more further directions, at least before I assume it's some form of extremely unlucky coincidence so that my hw stopped working at the same time of the update?

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same laptop and immediately upgraded to Zesty and I lost sound.

What finally worked for me (after a long night with tens of cold reboots) is adding the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

What didn't work for me was:

```
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m22
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=dell-laptop
# no sound: options snd-hda-intel model=generic
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=generic probe_mask=1 power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=generic probe_mask=1 power_save=0
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=generic probe_mask=1 power_save=0
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=generic probe_mask=1
# no sound: options snd-hda-intel model=generic power_save=0
# no card: options snd-hda-intel model=generic power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

I'm now left with an annoying inconvenience that `pulseaudio` is dead when first logging in. After running it, the working option is setting "analog output" in the device selection tab. I hope to sort this out soon too.